# divider line inside framed environment

Tags: framed

Adding a horizontal rule inside the framed environment, the line only spans the text area.
But i want the line to span the complete box width.

How do i do that?

Current Code:

```
\begin{framed}
Foo.\\
\rule{1\textwidth}{1pt}\\
Bar\\
\rule{1\textwidth}{1pt}\\
Baz
\end{framed}
```

**Current result:**

[image: Result]

**Expectation:**

[image: Expectation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me. It's not very generic though.

To make this work seamlessly in LyX (which outputs `\rule` for horizontal lines), I decided to re-define the `\rule` command to move the line 9pt to the left (which seems to be the inner padding of the `framed` environment) and make it 18pt longer:

```
\newlength{\framedline}
\setlength{\framedline}{\textwidth plus 18pt}
\let\oldrule\rule
\renewcommand{\rule}[2]{
   \hspace*{-9pt}\oldrule{\framedline}{0.4pt}\newline
}
```